# How to make two vertical columns in html

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have two divs in one row or have a two columns of divs.  It appears as one div under the other instead of a div next to a div.

CSS

```
#tacoh { 
margin: 200px 20% 40px 0;
float:right;
}

#hamburgerh { 
margin: 200px 40px 0 20% ;
float:left; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="hamburgerh" style="width:300px;height:350px;"></div>
<div id="tacoh" style="width:300px;height:350px;"></div>
```

Comment: Set `float:left;` to both divs.

Comment: wrap the divs inside a container, then use just float left and right, add the margin top and bottom to the container, its a better way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set a float left for both divs :

```
#tacoh { 
margin: 200px 20% 40px 0;
float:left;
}

#hamburgerh { 
margin: 200px 40px 0 20% ;
float:left; 
}
```

or wrap them into a container as Marius Balaj suggested :

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  margin: 200px 0 40px;
}

#tacoh { 
margin: 200px 20% 40px 0;
float:left;
}

#hamburgerh { 
margin: 200px 40px 0 20% ;
float:left; 
}
```

with the following html :

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="hamburgerh" style="width:300px;height:350px;"></div>
   <div id="tacoh" style="width:300px;height:350px;"></div>
</div>
```

Also since your style is the same for both divs, you could also create a class for them like below :

```
.w_300_h_350{
  width:300px;
  height:350px;
}
```

and apply it to you html like this :

```
<div id="hamburgerh" class="w_300h_350"></div>
<div id="tacoh" class="w_300h_350"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapit inside a container.

http://jsbin.com/qediqoxiwo/edit?css,output

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  margin: 200px 0 40px;
}

.col {
  float:left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  background:blue;
}

.col:last-child {
  float:right;
  background: red;
}
```